# checkbox not giving right state

Tags: java, android

I have one checkbox in my app which performes enabling\disabling bluetooth .. the problem is if I turn on\off from android setting(outside  this  app) then that checkbox is not updating like say if in app checkbox is checked means bluetooth is enable so now if I disable bluetooth from toggle or from system->settings and then go to my app then that checkbox is still checked ... how to get right state for that box ..(using fragment)

```
final BluetoothAdapter myBTadapter;
final Integer REQ_BT_ENABLE=1;
CheckBox enable;

myBTadapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
enable=(CheckBox)vv.findViewById(R.id.cboxEnable);
enable.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){    
        if(buttonView.isChecked()){
            if(myBTadapter==null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Device doesn't support Bluetooth",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                if(!myBTadapter.isEnabled()){
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.); 
                    startActivity(enableBtIntent);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Disabling Bluetooth!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            myBTadapter.disable();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: First, format your code and remove commented out lines. Then review your code again. If you still do not see your problem try to debug. Still cannot understand problem? Ask again.

Comment: in onResume() test whether BlueTooth is enabled or not and set your checkbox accordingly.

Comment: Can u post the code for onresume

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside onResume() method:

```
if(myBTadapter.isEnabled()) {
    enable.setChecked(true); 
} else {
    enable.setChecked(false); 
}
```

Comment: how to get  system cache ,system storage free and total size  ?